# how to bind a touch event with mapfragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to detect two scenario
 1. when a user tap into a google map
 2. when a user release that tap from the map
 It's like the touchevent which we use for other view like TextView, Linearlayout etc...
-Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H891w.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can create some kind of overlay over `MapFragment` and set `onTouchListener` to it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mapOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
View mapOverlay = (View) findViewById(R.id.mapOverlay);        
mapOverlay.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // handle tap
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // handlerelease
                break;
        }

        return false; // return false if you want propagate click to map
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually in <View>, there is I think typing mistake. It should be:-

android:id="@+id/mapOverlay"

Comment: I tried your code, but why MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is never called?

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario, use [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener). To get it working is pretty much self explanatory but here is an example for your convenience.

```
gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("LatLng", arg0.latitude + "-" + arg0.longitude);
        }
    });
```